# How to catch interrupts generated by TimeConstrained?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

*Mathematica* has the `CheckAbort` function which allows to catch and handle user-generated and programmatic `Abort`s. But it does not allow to catch interrupts generated by such functions as `TimeConstrained` and `MemoryConstrained`:

```
TimeConstrained[CheckAbort[Pause[100], Print["From CheckAbort"]], 1]
```

(does not print `"From CheckAbort"`).

Is there a way to catch such interrupts in *Mathematica*?

**EDIT:** I do know that third argument of `TimeConstrained` and `MemoryConstrained` allows to evaluate some code in the case of interrupt but this way is not what I need: I need a way to handle such interrupts entirely inside of my function allowing a user do not care of its internals.

P.S. The reason why I need this is that I have a function that creates `MathLink` objects which must be closed in the case of any interrupts or aborts but not in other cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The construct for this is available in undocumented form.

```
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  preprocessing,
  code,
  postprocessing]
```

will cause postprocessing to take place before returning from aborts or various types of jumps.

See also:

[Reliable clean-up in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365794/reliable-clean-up-in-mathematica)

[Import big files/arrays with mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica)

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: ``Internal`WithLocalSettings`` evaluates `postprocessing` in any case, not only when an interrupt happens. I need not to close `MathLink` connections after any evaluation of my function - only when some interrupt or abort happens.

Comment: This could work if a "done" flag is introduced, e.g. ``TimeConstrained[Module[{done=False},Internal`WithLocalSettings[Print@"start",Pause[100];done=True,If[!done, Print@"Interrupted!"]]], 5]``

Comment: @WReach Good idea! But your solution does not preserve the semantics of `TimeConstrained` that returns output from the function it the time constrain is met. I also wish to avoid double evaluation of the output of my function.

Comment: @Leonid I felt that your first edit is very close to solution but was unable to find the key - WReach has given it. I will post improved version of WReach's solution as a separate answer.

Comment: @Alexey Ok, the code by WReach is much simpler. I tried similar things but somehow missed this possibility. I will leave my answer for some time and then will delete it. It also sounds like a a good idea to post the answer based on the suggestion of WReach as a separate one.

Comment: @WReach Please disregard my previous comment - your suggestion is much closer to the OP needs than what I did

Comment: I used this function a lot recently, like this: `WithLocalSettings[Null, allocateMemoryInCFunction[]; ..., freeCMemory[]]`.  I learned about it from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1603/12).  Do you know about any caveats I should be aware of, other than the bad interaction with Throw/Catch that Leonid mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

Here is improved version of WReach's solution (he suggested it in a comment to the answer by Daniel Lichtblau). I should redefine my function `f` as follows (and now call it as `ff`):

```
ClearAll[ff];
SetAttributes[ff, HoldAllComplete];
ff[expr_] /; (Unset[done]; True) := 
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[Null, done = f[expr], 
  AbortProtect[If[! ValueQ[done], Print["Interrupt!"]]; Unset[done]]]
```

Examples:

```
ff[1 + 1]
(*=>f[2]*)
TimeConstrained[ff[Pause[10]; 1 + 1], 1]
(*=> prints "Interrupt!"*)
TimeConstrained[ff[Pause[.10]; 1 + 1], 1]
(*=>f[2]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeConstrained[Pause[100], 1, Print["-->Aborted"]]
```

and

```
MemoryConstrained[100!, 1, Print["-->Aborted"]]
```

Comment: I meant a way to catch aborts entirely inside of my function, allowing a user do not care of closing my `MathLink` connections.

Comment: @Alexey `outerFunc[x_]:=TimeConstrained[innerFunc[x],10, Print[..]]`? ... shieding it ...

Comment: I need not `TimeConstrained` inside of my function. I just wish to allow a user to use it without risk to run into problems.

Comment: @Alexey Could you post an example of your intended usage? One not covered by the third argument, I mean.

Comment: Given `f[expr]` as my `MathLink` function which evaluates `expr` in a slave kernel, I wish to allow a user to write `TimeConstrained[f[expr],10]` without care of internals of `f` (without using of the third argument).

Comment: I just have realized that it probably may be made by defining an `UpValue` for `f`. But it will work only if `f` is on level 1 inside of `TimeConstrained`.

Comment: @Alexey You could also redefine `TimeConstrained` to do wht you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003224/trouble-redefining-an-internal-function

Comment: I do not like to redefine built-in functions but is seems that in this case it is the only possibility. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here just to flesh out Danny's answer.  I think this is clearly a bug in `CheckAbort`, and would use this as a workaround:

```
Attributes[myCheckAbort] = {HoldAll};
myCheckAbort[arg1_, arg2_] := Block[
    {res, aborted},
    WithCleanup[
        aborted = True
        ,
        res = arg1;
        aborted = False;
        res
        ,
        If[aborted,
            arg2;
            res = $Aborted
        ]
    ]
]
```